# How to get the status of Kubernetes nodes via the client?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I want to get the list of the nodes and their status in Kubernetes via the go client. I am using
`clientset.CoreV1().Nodes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})`
and I am able to get the list of nodes and some information such as node lables but I cannot find the `status.phase` there (for pods that give me the status).

I searched and I found `NodeCondition` (https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/9b64426eca51a74faa7cc9bd732a533d339c69c2/core/v1/types.go#L4911) but I cannot find any documentation regarding how to use it and I couldn't make it work myself. Can someone please let me know how I can get the status of Nodes via the client?

Comment: That was very helpful but now I am trying to patch the node condition type status, any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access it through `node.Status.Condition`

```
nodes, _ := client.CoreV1().Nodes().List(context.TODO(), metav1.ListOptions{})

for _, node := range nodes.Items {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", node.Name)
    for _, condition := range node.Status.Conditions {
        fmt.Printf("\t%s: %s\n", condition.Type, condition.Status)
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
dev-master-01
        NetworkUnavailable: False
        MemoryPressure: False
        DiskPressure: False
        PIDPressure: False
        Ready: True
dev-master-02
        NetworkUnavailable: False
        MemoryPressure: False
        DiskPressure: False
        PIDPressure: False
        Ready: True
dev-master-03
        NetworkUnavailable: False
        MemoryPressure: False
        DiskPressure: False
        PIDPressure: False
        Ready: True
```

Comment: Perfect, How can I patch the node condition status? any idea?